# Issues with inheritance in Backbone/Coffeescript

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, coffeescript

So I'm starting this new app using Backbone/CoffeeScript. I'm using a back end of Sinatra, so my Coffeescript compiler is the default command line one which just creates the js files. I'm trying to create an app where there is a master class which other classes inherit from. For some reason I'm getting a few errors. Here are the errors

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'n.replace')
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'parent.prototype')
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new FileApp.UploaderView()')
```

Here is my base class

```
class FileApp.Controller extends Backbone.View
template: _.template($('#FileAppTemplate').html())

initialize: (office) ->
    @office = office
    @render()

render:  ->
    # Attach view to DOM
    $('#fileUploaderApp').append(@$el)


bindViews: (uploaderView, fileViewerView, fileDetailView) ->
    @uploaderView = uploaderView
    @fileViewerView = fileViewerView
    @fileDetailView = fileDetailView
```

Here is an example of an inheriting class

```
 class FileApp.FileViewerView extends FileApp.Controller 

template: _.template($('#FileViewTemplate').html())

# 
# render ->
# 
render: ->
    @$el.html(@template)
    # Append to fileViewer Div

    @renderFiles()

# 
# createFiles ->
# 
renderFiles: ->
```

And here is how my .erb file is loading each item and instantiating the app.

```
<script id="namespacing">
    //All backbone classes attach to this variable
    var FileApp={};
</script>

<!-- Underscrore/Backbone -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>


<script src="/js/fileUploader/libs/file_app_view.js"></script>
<script src="/js/fileUploader/libs/uploader_view.js"></script>
<script src="/js/fileUploader/libs/file_detail_view.js"></script>
<script src="/js/fileUploader/libs/file_model.js"></script>
<script src="/js/fileUploader/libs/file_viewer_view.js"></script>
<script src="/js/fileUploader/libs/file_view.js"></script>


<div id="fileUploaderApp"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var App = new FileApp.Controller();

        // # Create Uploader
        var uploaderView = new FileApp.UploaderView();
        // # Create File Viewer
        var fileViewerView = new FileApp.FileViewerView();
        // # Create File Detail View
        var fileDetailView = new FileApp.FileDetailView();

        App.bindViews(uploaderView, fileViewerView, fileDetailView)
    });
</script>
```

If anyone can clarify what my issue is That'd be great.

Comment: Is this your real code? If yes, you have to indent the class's methods. Leading whitespace is significant in Coffeescript.

Comment: No... I guess it got messed pasting here. The indentation in my code is right I believe. It surely doesn't look like that above..

Comment: Don't mix tabs and spaces, at the very least.

Comment: They aren't mixed. My tabbing is correct. I double checked.

Comment: Sometimes it can happen that coffeescript isn't compiled in the way we expected, have you checked your compiled js files for some error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this by compiling my .coffee files into one .js file. It seemed that with inheriting It was simply an issue of being able to see the classes i was trying to inherit from. Since Coffeescript puts all files in a closure, my classes couldn't access other classes to inherit from.

I tried to handle it with namespacing at first, but everyone knows how easy that is with coffeescript...

Ultimately, I resolved it by just making one .js file (a better result either way).

If anyone else ever needs to compile many files into one file here is the bash command I am using. It places a file "app.js" in the current dir's "libs/" dir and compiles all files from the current dir's "src/" dir.

```
 coffee --output libs --join app.js --compile --watch src/
```

Thanks for the help everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@$el.html(@template())
```

instead of

```
@$el.html(@template)
```

Also, you will want to pass parameter to template

```
@$el.html(@template(parameter1: 'value1', parameter2: 'value2'))
```

Usually in your view you have a model, if your model is office, which is a backbone model you can do:

```
@$el.html(@template(var_referencing_office.toJSON()))
```

This is just an example. I don't know whether you passing office to this view.